# Screen/view shifting between activities

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, start-activity

Complete newbie here...when I call a second activity from a first activity the screen view kind of jumps/shifts. The same happens when I hit the back button to return to the first activity. The files were generated by Android Studio and I've only added a button with onClick to call the second activity, and modified the actionbar text. Hope the screen recording illustrates. Any ideas what might be causing it?

**screen recording converted to animated gif**

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enter_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.philburfitt.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // change text on actionbar
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Test - First Activity");

        // call Main2Activity on button press
        Button enterButton = findViewById(R.id.enter_button);
        enterButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View v ) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Main2Activity.java

```
package com.philburfitt.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Test - Second Activity");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check '' Don't keep Activity " ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=14&v=THjU5JTtusc&feature=emb_logo

Comment: Ok, set, but unfortunately no change:(

Comment: try to use `Fragment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have seen is the default transition ,however you can use custom transitions . I will share a sample .

This is how i call next activity B from activity A.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
       startActivity(i);
       finish();
       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

Now Add this animation files in res>anim

slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
</set>
```

Comment: Thank you @Vish. overridePendingTransition( 0, 0 ) did the job.